# Gluon Propagator

Tags: path-integral, propagator, gluons

The photon propagator is obtained from the Yang-Mills Lagrangian applying the Faddeev-Popv procedure:

$$D_{\mu\nu}(k) ~=~ \frac{i}{k^2}[-g_{\mu\nu} + (1-\zeta)\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}]$$

To get to the gluon propagator from here, we just multiply an extra color factor of $\delta_{ab}$. It is not obvious to me why. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Did you expect a different result?

Comment: I did not expect the kronecker delta.

Comment: That just says the color stays the same, though.

Comment: The gluon field carries color, so there must be color indices in the gluon propagator.

Comment: okay, so its something we put in by hand then? to say that the color stays the same?

Comment: It comes from the normalization of the generators $Tr (T^a T^b) = C \delta^{ab}$.

Comment: How exactly does that influence this calculation?

Answer (score 4):

The quadratic part of the Lagrangian of the gluon is exactly the same as the photon Lagrangian, except that the fields have color indices:
\begin{equation}
(\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a)(\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a)
\end{equation}
which is the same as
\begin{equation}
\delta^{ab} (\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a)(\partial_\mu A_\nu^b - \partial_\nu A_\mu^b)
\end{equation}
whence the $\delta$.